# Is it possible to create an advanced login dialog for a Java Webstart application?

Tags: java, security, authentication, java-web-start

I implemented an advanced login dialog for a webstart application. I call it "advanced" because it consists of three screens: one for the actual login (user, password), one for password retrieval, and one for new user registration. The problem I am having is that the webstart support for login dialogs is somewhat poor. The server simply sends a callback object to the client asking for a username and password. The client can then show a dialog or not (depending on use case). Unfortunately the dialog does not seem have any other hooks or connections to the server (in my case Glassfish 2.1). Does anyone know how I can still implement the advanced features?

Dirk

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented (even more) advanced JWS login window without problems. Just make that window the initial `JFrame` launched by your `Main-Class`, and everything is fine. I.e. nothing special for the fact that it is a login screen - it's just the initial screen.